# InstallShield: How to add to component condition a variable called PATCH?

Tags: installshield

I have the following component condition: `NOT Installed OR ((Installed AND NOT REINSTALL) AND NOT REMOVE~="ALL")`

I want to know where I should add 'PATCH' so that it runs when it is a PATCH as well.

Is this correct?: `NOT Installed OR (PATCH AND (Installed AND NOT REINSTALL) AND NOT REMOVE~="ALL")`

Answer (score 0):

Just getting back to InstallShield again, but...you are going to execute the CA if it is both Not installed, or Installed and it is a patch?

Create a very small test installer and test the various possible conditions.

Comment: I figured out to do something so simple; NOT REMOVE~="ALL"; it covers both; first time install, if its already installed (repair); and if a upgrade (patch). Capiche?